# golang v.latest написал простой сервер, который не запустился

Tags: golang

Написал сервер:

```
package program

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Server is waiting and may print inputs,press any key to exit.")
    var isNeed bool = true
    mloop(&isNeed)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for true {
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if text != "" {
            isNeed = false
            break
        }
    }
    return
}
func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    return
}
func mloop(isNeed *bool) {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9090")
    check(err)
    for *isNeed == true {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        check(err)
        go handleM(conn, isNeed)
    }
    return
}
func handleM(conn net.Conn, isNeed *bool) {
    tmp := make([]byte, 256)
    var name string = conn.RemoteAddr().String()
    for *isNeed == true {
        n, err := conn.Read(tmp)
        check(err)
        if string(tmp) == "\"END\"" {
            fmt.Println(name + " left")
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(name + "sad: \"" + string(tmp) + "\" ,msg length is" + strconv.Itoa(n))
    }
}
```

Он компилируется, компилятор молчит, но вот при попытке запуска пишет:

```
tema2@DESKTOP-KPPHKQ0 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/lulz
$ go build -o server.exe ./server.go

tema2@DESKTOP-KPPHKQ0 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/lulz
$ ./server.exe
./server.exe: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./server.exe: line 1: `!<arch>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что Ваш пакет называется не `main`, а `program`. По сути, точкой входа в программу является `func main()` в пакете `main`. Но это поведение можно немного хакнуть. Для этого придумана функция `func init()`. Эта функция выполнится перед выполнением `func main()`. Эту функцию так же можно писать в Ваших пакетах. Она всегда будет выполняться при импорте пакета (если быть точным — она выполнится один раз при первом импорте пакета в вашей программе). Так же стоит понимать, что `init()` выполнится и при запуске тестов этого пакета.